# How to print all the string after matching a string in python

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7

a. I have a line as given below:

```
HELLO CMD-LINE: hello how are you -color blue how is life going -color red,green life is pretty -color orange,violet,red
```

b. I wanted to print the string after `-color`.

c. I tried the below reg exp method,

```
for i in range (len(tar_read_sp)):
print tar_read_sp[i]
wordy = re.findall(r'-color.(\w+)', tar_read_sp[i], re.M|re.I|re.U)
# print "%s"%(wordy.group(0))
if wordy:
    print "Matched"
    print "Full match: %s" % (wordy)
    print "Full match: %s" % (wordy[0])
    # wordy_ls = wordy.group(0).split('=')
    # print wordy_ls[1]
    # break 
else:
    print "Not Matched"
```

but it prints only the first word matching after the string like,
`['blue', 'red', 'orange']`.

c. But how to print all the string after matching string? like
`['blue', 'red', 'green', 'orange', 'violet']` and remove the repeating variable?

Please share your comments and suggestions to print the same?

Comment: fix your indentation.....try `(?:-color.((?:\w+,?)+))` and then use `split()`

Answer (score 0):

Agree with depperm: fix your indentation.

Using his regex suggestion and combining it with the necessary split, de-duping, and re-ordering the list:

```
wordy = re.findall(r'(?:-color.((?:\w+,?)+))', test_string, re.M|re.I|re.U)
wordy = list({new_word for word in wordy for new_word in word.split(',')})[::-1]
```

That should give you a flattened, unique list like you asked for (at least I assume that's what you mean by "remove the repeating variable").

Answer (score 0):

My personal preference would to do something like this:

```
import re

tar_read_sp = "hello how are you -color blue how is life going -color red,green life is pretty -color orange,violet,red"

wordy = re.findall(r'-color.([^\s]+)', tar_read_sp, re.I)

big_list = []
for match in wordy:
    small_list = match.split(',')
    big_list.extend(small_list)

big_set = list(set(big_list))
print (big_set)
```

I find this approach a little easier to read and update down the road.  The idea is to get all those color matches, build a big list of them, and the use set to dedupe it.  The regex I'm using:

```
-color ([^\s])+
```

Will capture the 'small_list' of colors up the the next space.

Answer (score 0):

I have a solution not using regex.

```
test_string = 'hello how are you -color blue how is life going -color red,green life is pretty -color orange,violet,red'
result = []
for colors in [after_color.split(' ')[1] for after_color in test_string.split('-color')[1:]]:
    result = result+colors.split(',')
print result
```

The result is:
['blue', 'red', 'green', 'orange', 'violet', 'red']